# Expected identifier while trying to compile

Tags: c, cs50

Trying to do `cs50` without the `cs50` `GetString`.

Got stuck by doing the new function included in the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PrintName(char name);

{
printf("Your name is %c\n", name);
}

int main();
{
char fio[10];

printf("Hello, ");

scanf("%c", &fio);

PrintName(fio);

return 0;
}
```

Says the next:

```
hello-0.c:9:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
hello-0.c:14:1: error: expected identifier or '('
{
^
```

What it could be?

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <math.h>`  Nothing in the posted code uses anything from the header file: `math.h`.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used.  Suggest removing that statement.  Similar considerations exist for `#include <string.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%c", &fio);`  1) the variable `fio` is an array.  Reference a bare array name degrades to the address of the first byte of the array,  So this statement will not compile.  Suggest removing the `&`, so the compiler just sees the `fio` as the address of the first byte of `fio`  2) the 'input format conversion' specifier `%c` is used to input a single character.  To input a string of characters, use the 'input format conversion' specifier `%s`  Also, the specifier `%s` always append a NUL byte, so use a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer.

Comment: Regarding: `printf("Your name is %c\n", name);`  The 'output format conversion' specifier only outputs a single character.  Per your code, you want to output a character string.  Therefore, you need to use the 'output format conversion' specifier `%s`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, you have extra semi-colons: in front of `main` and `PrintName` function. Remove them.

Secondly, you created char array (aka string) and you `scanf`-ed it wrong. If you want to get name as string (not as a char, as you did), you have to do it like this:

```
char fio[10];

printf("Hello, ");

scanf("%9s", fio);
```

Note that, as I am reading string, my format is `%s` (note 9 in there to read up to 9 characters, because you have array of 10). Moreover, I pass the address of my char array (which is already an address). That's how you read a string. And printing it in function will be:

```
void PrintName(char name[])
{
    printf("Your name is %s\n", name);
}
```

where we pass `char[]` to function and again print with `%s` format

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", fio);`  the array `fio[]` is only 10 characters long and always need room for the NUL termination byte.  Therefore, if the user enters a name that is more than 9 characters long then a buffer overflow will occur, resulting in undefined behavior (and perhaps a seg fault event).   To assure the user does not overflow the buffer, place a MAX CHARACTERs modifier that 1 less than the length of the input buffer.  I.E. `scanf("%9s", fio);`

Comment: Thank you a lot, it compiles. And now i've clear a moments about buffer.